Excel Chart: center align resized plot area
How do you center align a resized PlotArea?
With objChart
    .Left = myChtRange.Left
    .Top = myChtRange.Top
    .Width = myChtRange.Width
    .Height = myChtRange.Height
    With .Chart
        '=====================
        Dim temp As Integer
        With .PlotArea
            temp = .Width
            temp = .Height
            temp = .Left
            temp = .Top
            .Width = 200
            .Height = 100
            '.Left = 10
            '.Top = 10
            .Left = (objChart.Width - objChart.Chart.PlotArea.Width) / 2
            .Top = (objChart.Height - objChart.Chart.PlotArea.Height) / 2
            '.Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic
        End With
        '=====================
    End With
End With

This does not center align the PlotArea:
        With .PlotArea
            .Left = (objChart.Width - objChart.Chart.PlotArea.Width) / 2

This does center align the PlotArea but also resets its size:
        With .PlotArea
            .Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic

EDIT
1

2


Pls explain on the specific issues you encountered. A screenshot with comment is helpful.

Screenshot 1: using .Left = (objChart.Width - objChart.Chart.PlotArea.Width) / 2 -> PlotArea is to far to the right. Screenshot 2: using .Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic -> PlotArea is centerd, but the size is resetted.

For screenshot 1,  The right gap will decrease if the plot area width is increased.

I've increased the plot area width to three different values: the right gap is always narrower than the left gap.

Pls try to hide Y axis. It may take space.

The same outcome.

You can't set the size of the plotarea if it's going to be limited by the available space to the right or below (Height/Width may end up less then the value you provide), so set the Top/Left first.
This works for me:
Sub Tester()
    Const H As Long = 250
    Const W As Long = 250
    Dim ws As Worksheet, co As ChartObject
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("chart")
    Set co = ws.ChartObjects("Wykres2")
    With co.Chart.PlotArea
        .Left = (co.Width - W) / 2
        .Top = (co.Height - H) / 2
        .Width = W
        .Height = H
    End With
End Sub

...assuming the chartobject is large enough.

Ok. But the PlotArea is not (yet) centered. Is has the same position as in Screenshot 1.  Is it perfectly centered on your machine? Might it be a version thing? I'm using Excel 2016.

I'm on Office 365 (Windows)
